# How to limit the data entry to database in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

How could I limit the data that I am writing to the database.

I am trying to map Bank details to Districts. I would like to limit the entry of Bank details to 1 District.

To be precise, user should only be able to create a bank name for a district. When they try to create a new record they would be treated with error stating that only One record should be created.

Database Tables:

```
District 
| id 
| district_name

Bank
| id 
| bank_name
| district_id
```

I have thought of showing the data of the districts that not in the bank table to a select menu.

How would I limit that in eloquent relationship or are there any other options,

Another option is to limit the result to the latest creates bank Id. But I dont think this is a good idea to consider.

What I tried,

Bank Controller,

use Bank;

```
 public function create()
    {
        $districts = Districts::all();
        $banks = Bank::all();
        foreach($banks->districts as $bank)
        $banks1 = $bank->district_name;
        return($bank1);

        // return view('bank-create',compact('districts'));
    }
```

The above code is not working, I just tried and I was not able to get through it.

I was expecting the result of the query to pass in to below select,

```
 <select name="district_option1" class="form-control  ml-5" id="">
                        @foreach ($bank1 as $banks1)
                        <option value="{{$banks1->id}}">{{$banks1->district_name}} </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
```

My Model:

Bank

```
public function districts(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Districts','district_id','id');
}
```

District :

```
 public function bank(){
     return $this->hasOne('App\Bank','id','district_id'); }
```

Comment: Your error is that you are not getting all bank in select dropdown?

Comment: Your foreach loop is not right

Comment: Add your inputs as well

Comment: sorry if question has confused you, I am trying to add a new bank if there is no bank attached to the district. I found out a way to limit that by not showing the district in the select drop down.  @KamalPaliwal

Comment: @ElnurIbrahim-zade Yeah the codes are wrong, I was trying to project my idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `unique` validation for this purpose.

```
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
           'district_id' => 'reuqired|unique:banks,district_id'
        ]);
     }
```

Here you are checking if there are any records for this district.

Comment: I added to this to my controller still, there is an entry. Also it's only restricting the duplicate name